# I have a Contact form, and i'm try to connect it with PHP mail using Angularjs and get get data in php file

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('snc', []);

  app.controller("QueryController", function($http) {
    this.query = {};

    this.sendQuery = function(contact) {
      contact.querys.push(this.query);
      this.query = {};
    };
  });

})();
```

```html
<form name="queryForm" ng-controller="QueryController as queryCtrl" ng-submit="queryForm.$valid && queryCtrl.sendQuery(contact)" novalidate>
  <blockquote>
    <b>Name: {{queryCtrl.query.name}}</b><br/>
    <b>Mobile: {{queryCtrl.query.mobile}}</b><br/>
    <b>Eamil: {{queryCtrl.query.email}}</b><br/>
    <b>Message: {{queryCtrl.query.message}}</b><br/>
  </blockquote>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="queryCtrl.query.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Mobile">Mobile:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="queryCtrl.query.mobile" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="queryCtrl.query.email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Message">Message:</label>
    <textarea type="text" ng-model="queryCtrl.query.message" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Message" rows="4" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div> reviewForm is {{queryForm.$valid}} </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-snc">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm Using *ng-app="snc"* and Angularjs version 1.6, this is a simple contact form please check it and give me some advice. i want to send contact form into php page, where i use form data for send email for query and add it into database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample code

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('snc', []);
  app.controller('QueryController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.query = {};
    $scope.submit = function() {

      console.log($scope.query);
      $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "", //php url
        data: {
          query
        }
      }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }, function myError(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
    };

  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="fromvalue" ng-app="snc" ng-controller="QueryController">
  <b>Name: {{query.name}}</b><br/>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="query.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
  </div>
  <div> reviewForm is {{fromvalue.$valid}} </div>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-snc">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How to show show success and error message in this form  and how to get value in php file